# Set a mongo database in pymongo without eval(). Maybe setattr()?

Tags: python, mongodb, eval, pymongo, setattr

I'd been used to doing this in pymongo as a means of accessing a particular database:

```
import pymongo

connection = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = connection.DBNAME
```

then querying db.collectioname.find(), etc.  However, I now want to be able to connect to databases named via variable, with an eye to looping over a series of databases.  So something like:

```
dbname = 'DBNAME'

connection = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = eval('connection.' + dbname)
```

I have been taught that eval() is occasionally the devil and should be avoided.  How can I do this with setattr() or other solution?  Something like...

```
dbname = 'DBNAME'

connection = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = setattr(connection, '??name??', dbname)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr), not `setattr`.

```
db = getattr(connection,dbname)
```

where `setattr` is a way to *set* an attribute if you know it's name, `getattr` is a way to *get* an attribute if you know it's name.

In other words, the following are 100% equivalent:

```
db = connection.DBNAME
db = getattr(connection,'DBNAME')
```

Comment: Yep, thank you, that's very helpful.  I wasn't sure that I knew that the database name was properly an attribute.  When I typed `dir(connection)`, I didn't see it!